# onClickListener not triggering

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm doing a rather round about way of making a solitaire app.  What's happening right now is that I'm trying to click on a button that is supposed to deal cards from the deck to the state that you can play cards from.  However, the listener is never triggering.

I put a system.out.println statement in to test to see if it ever enters the code block with the listener, and it does not.

```
    public class SolitaireGame extends Activity {
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.game);

      buttonSound = MediaPlayer.create(SolitaireGame.this, R.raw.button_click);
      //instance variables
      theDeck = new Deck();
      botCardStacks = new ArrayList<BotCardStack>(7);
      aceStacks = new ArrayList<AceCardStack>(4);
      playableCards = new CardStack(52);

      deckButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.deckButton);
      deckButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            buttonSound.start();
            dealCardsToPlayableStack();                
          }
        });
```

As requested, here is my add cards to playable stack method

```
    public void dealCardsToPlayableStack() {
      Stack<Card> tempStack = new Stack<Card>();
      int i = 0;
      Card temp, temp1, temp2, temp3;

      if(theDeck.getValueOfNext() == 0) {
          while(!playableCards.isEmpty()) {
              temp = playableCards.popCard();
              temp.setVisible(false);
              tempStack.push(temp);
          }
          while(!tempStack.isEmpty()) {
              theDeck.addCard(tempStack.pop());
          }
      }

      else if(theDeck.getValueOfNext() >= 3) {
          temp1 = theDeck.popCard();
          temp1.setVisible(true);
          temp2 = theDeck.popCard();
          temp2.setVisible(true);
          temp3 = theDeck.popCard();
          temp3.setVisible(true);

          playableCards.addCard(temp3);
          playableCards.addCard(temp2);
          playableCards.addCard(temp1);
      }

      else if(theDeck.getValueOfNext() == 2) {
          temp1 = theDeck.popCard();
          temp1.setVisible(true);
          temp2 = theDeck.popCard();
          temp2.setVisible(true);

          playableCards.addCard(temp2);
          playableCards.addCard(temp1);
      }

      else if(theDeck.getValueOfNext() == 1) {
          temp1 = theDeck.popCard();
          temp1.setVisible(true);

          playableCards.addCard(temp1);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `buttonSound.prepare()` before `buttonSound.start()` (I prefer using SoudPool Class instead of Mediaplayer for sound effects as it is less costly in memory). Secondly, can you share the `dealCardsToPlayableStack()` method. You can put it outside the `onClick()` method (in `onCreate())` and if you have the same behaviour, then the problem is in this method, not the `OnClick()` method.

Comment: Sorry for the super late response.  Finals and the Holidays came up in between, and I as spending my time elsewhere.